# Optaplanner - Why switching from mode full_assert to another gives totally different results?

Tags: optaplanner

I am developing a solver using drools to find the most likely date (start date = planningVariable) for which a medical analysis (planningEntity) will start. Then i calculate other dates from it whose calculation does not depend on the optaplanner mechanism (end date and other intermediate dates). For my problem, I need each rule to fire whenever the planningVariable value change.

When using FULL_ASSERT mode everything works but when i change to another mode, results are a mess. Almost no rule is respected or the solution gives null values and i don't understand why.

Is it because the full_assert mode is the only one that guarantees to fire all rules each time the planningVariable value changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`, that doesn't trigger more **fireAllRules()**.

Either way, switching on FULL_ASSERT etc, shouldn't change the behavior (unless you're explicitly using simulated annealing with walk clock time because it is time gradient sensitive). If it does change behavior, it's probably due to some sort of corruption. All the more reasons to run `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT` and figure out where.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

I tried NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT and it also worked fine (same as FULL_ASSERT) but when I try other mode I have different results (and false). 

I am using a time limit of 300ms (<millisecondsSpentLimit>) because I want the calculation to be done as quickly as possible. Can this explain the change in behavior for other modes?

Comment: Yes, the assert modes are 100 times slower or so. It probalby doesn't reach the bad code. Give them more time to crash.